# Conditional groupings in Cognos 10

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am developing a report for a University.  They require around 15 different groupings of their choice (e.g. Campus, Faculty, Course, School, Program, Major, Minor, Nationality, Mode of Study... and the list goes on).
They require the Headcount and EFTS (Equivalent Full Time Student) for each of these groupings.

They may require a single grouping, a selection in any order of groupings, or all groupings.

A solution was provided here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014834406#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014837873

The solutions suggests to use conditional blocks and multiple lists.  However that would mean I would have 50+ lists, every possible combination of my groups (e.g. Campus + Faculty , Campus + School, School + Faculty, Faculty + Campus .... )

Is these any way for users to dynamically select the order of their groupings, and which groups to exclude/include?  Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify? By grouping do you mean grouping in Cognos lists? How are your users going to select the groupings? Check boxes? What should the output look like? You mention order. Do you mean the order that the groupings are selected or the sorting of the data?

Comment: Yes in Cognos lists.  I am not sure what the interface would look like in Cognos but we do have a custom solution.  It has 4 drop down lists.  The 1st ddl relates to the 1st grouping, 2nd ddl to 2nd grouping and so on.  So currently we have a max of 4 combinations.  A ddl contains {Campus, Faculty, School ... }.  Hope this is clear.